# How to fix rsLogonFailed error message when executing report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I just installed SQL 2012 Enterprise on a laptop running windows 10 Pro x64.
When I try to execute my SSRS reports from the report manager, I always get the same error:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot impersonate user for data source 'DataSource1'. (rsErrorImpersonatingUser)
Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct. (rsLogonFailed)
The user name or password is incorrect

I am using integrated windows authentication with a domain account.
The domain account can log on through SSMS and can access the databases with no issue and run queries.

I have also tried using a local SQL account and password but with the same result - The username or password is incorrect, yet this account works through SSMS and is able to execute queries and such.

When i click the Test Connection button in SSRS datasource configuration, it states the connection was created successfully. (I have included a shot of what I am talking about in the uploaded image)

After googling, people stated that the account that is being used to connect to the database using windows impersonation had to have log on locally permissions, so I added the account through local security Policy, but it made no difference.

Another blog  stated the SSRS Service account had to also be granted log on locally permissions - so I granted it the log on locally permission as well. Still to no avail.

I have also tried disabling the windows firewall and connecting to both the machine name and localhost just in case there was some screwy rules regarding localhost - still with the same result.

Other people suggested the execution account in SSRS manager needed be disabled. I didn't set this up initially - but set the account up just in case it had something to do with it - still with the same error then removed it again still with the same error.

Can anyone offer any other suggestions as to what might be the cause and how I might fix this?

Many thanks and Cheers

Rod.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using a Shared Data Source in the report?

Comment: Yes - i just double checked the report and its using a shared data source. I published the report to another SSRS Server running SQL 2012 as well just to confirm and it executes fine on that server with the credentials.

Comment: OK - so after re-installing SQL Server I managed to get one report to run - the rest are still giving me the error mentioned above. Unbelievably frustrating. :(

Answer (score 2):

OK - managed to work out the problem and a workaround. But it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Problem is Chrome and IE11 wont update the Reports web site when managing datasources. Even when launched as administrator, the SSRS management interface site does not appear to save the changes. Edge is just a joke so don't even bother with that one.

Now - I figured Microsoft has broken something which SSRS interface needs in windows 10, so I logged onto a Windows 7 machine and using IE11, was able to navigate to report manager site, update the credentials (windows and SQL Server credentials) and the reports run.

Confirmed this by trying to change the credentials back on windows 10 and it immediately broke the reports again. Set the credentials back in Win 7 and it corrected the reports.

So if you are using windows 10 and are having issues configuring credentials for SSRS reports, try logging in from a windows 7 machine and set through IE on that machine.

EDIT: IE11 works on older windows 10 build  (enterprise) , latest build (Pro) seems to be broken.

Cheers

Rod.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

Go to Report Configuration Manager
Go to Excution Account
Enter Domain\UserAccount   [User Account is your windows User]
Enter Password     [Windows Password]

Save and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified an unattended execution account, SSRS flip-flops between impersonating it and the identity specified in your data source during the rendering process. If you use an unattended execution account, you’ve got to keep the password up-to-date.

You could also choose not to use the unattended execution account at all, which may also solve your problem. For more detail see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2006/08/16/702490.aspx

Comment: I know this is a very late comment to reply - but I checked and the unattended execution account was not configured at all - so I don't think it is flipping between the unattended execution account and the configured data source login - but thanks for the info. I still have this issue on win 10 pro - can configure data source from windows 7, not from windows 10 :(